# Pandas equivalent to dense rank

Tags: python, pandas, dense-rank

I am trying to copy a dense rank SQL statement in pandas.
The SQL statement looks as follows:

```
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Team],[Season] ORDER BY [Team], 
       [Season],CAST([characteristic].[value] AS INT) DESC)  AS ROW#
```

The python code I have tried so far, ranks only over one column, instead of two.

```
    df['Rank'] = df1.Team.rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: It seems that some part of the SQL code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df[['Rank1', 'Rank2']] = df1[['Team','Season']].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```